# Running multiple timeouts simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

Is there any way of moving between switch statements so both divs will loop?

I'm writing a desktop app that recommends different things to do based on what interests you input. Right now, we have music and video game genres. They are selected by using dropdown menus. The genres are in their own functions. These functions are called on change by the drop down menu, as seen here

```
<select id="vg" class="dropdown" onchange="vgchosen.call(this, event)">
<select id="music" class="dropdown" onchange="muchosen.call(this, event)">
```

when a genre is picked, a div tag starts looping text, giving you ideas on what to do.

```
<div id="vgc" class="genres">Game Genres Here</div>
<div id="muc" class="genres">Music Genres Here</div>
```

some of the text looped can be seen here

```
case "Action":
    var actionvgc = [
    "You should play |Skyrim",
    "You should play |Killing Floor 2",
    "You Should play |Counter Strike Global Offensive",
    ];
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = setInterval(function() {  var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * actionvgc.length);
        if (i == actionvgc.length) --i;
        $("#vgc").html(actionvgc[i]); }, 1000);
        break;

case "Pop":
    var popmuc = [
    "You should listen to |Maroon 5",
    "You should listen to |Nicki Minaj",
    "You Should listen to |5 Seconds of Summer",
    ];
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = setInterval(function() {  var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * popmuc.length);
        if (i == popmuc.length) --i;
        $("#muc").html(popmuc[i]); }, 1000);
        break;
```

everything works when you first pick a genre, text is looped, everyone is happy. The issue arises when you try to pick a genre from the other drop down menu. Ex: you picked action games, you see action games. You pick pop music, you see pop music, but actions games has stopped looping.

Answer (score 1):

You should set two different timerId intervals, because the way you are doing it, you will always clear the interval you set before, no matter if music or games are selected:

```
var timerIdForGames, timerIdForMusic;
case "Action":
    var actionvgc = [
    "You should play |Skyrim",
    "You should play |Killing Floor 2",
    "You Should play |Counter Strike Global Offensive",
    ];
    clearInterval(timerIdForGames);
    timerIdForGames = setInterval(function() {  var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * actionvgc.length);
        if (i == actionvgc.length) --i;
        $("#vgc").html(actionvgc[i]); }, 1000);
        break;

case "Pop":
    var popmuc = [
    "You should listen to |Maroon 5",
    "You should listen to |Nicki Minaj",
    "You Should listen to |5 Seconds of Summer",
    ];
    clearInterval(timerIdForMusic);
    timerIdForMusic = setInterval(function() {  var i = Math.round((Math.random()) * popmuc.length);
        if (i == popmuc.length) --i;
        $("#muc").html(popmuc[i]); }, 1000);
        break;
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer. you and @Stephan Muller are wonderful

Comment: No problem. Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your `setTimeout` by both assigning them to the variable `timerId`.

Give them both unique names and they will be able to run simultaneously.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The quick response was astonishing. I am so grateful for this website